# surround each of the array items with the `^` sign excluding repeated ones

Tags: javascript, regex

Thanks to @[Konrad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5089567/konrad) we can surround each of the array items with the `^` sign like this:

```js
const signs = [',', '!!', '?!', '!?', '...', '..', '.', '?', '؟!', '!؟', '!', '؟', ':'];

const input = 'this is, a text?'

const str = signs.map(e => e.replace(/\?/g, '\\?').replace(/\./g, '\\.')).join('|')

const regex = new RegExp(` ?(${str}) ?`, 'g')

const result = input.replace(regex, ' ^$1^ ').trim()

console.log(result)
```

Now the issue is if you have this input as the string:

`this is ^,^ a text ^?^ ?` you will get a repetition of  `^` sign and we don't want this:

`this is ^ ^,^ ^ a text ^ ^?^ ^ ^?^`

Here is the desired result actually :

`this is ^,^ a text ^?^ ^?^`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```js
const signs = [',', '!!', '?!', '!?', '...', '..', '.', '?', '؟!', '!؟', '!', '؟', ':'];

const input = 'this is ^,^ a text ^?^ ?'

const str = signs.map(e => e.replace(/\?/g, '\\?').replace(/\./g, '\\.')).join('|')

const regex = new RegExp(`\\s*(?:\\^\\s*)*(${str})\\s*(?:\\^\\s*)*`, 'g')

const result = input.replace(regex, ' ^$1^ ').trim()

console.log(result)
```

Here, I added `(?:\\^\\s*)*` on both ends to match zero or more sequences of `^` and zero or more whitespaces, and replaced the literal space with `\\s*` to match any zero or more whitespaces.

Note that escaping is better done with the universal solution like in [Is there a RegExp.escape function in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3561493/3832970):

```js
const str = signs.map(e => e.replace(/[-\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')).join('|')
```

Comment: let me try this, thanks ...

Comment: Amazing .......